# Proper design for a custom allocator for std::list

Tags: c++, allocator

I've written a custom allocator as a proof of concept. To test it, I've used the `std::list` container.

Sadly, the program crashed during the destruction of the list (i'm not here asking to find the bug, since i've already done, or at least am sure i have).

My custom allocator simply allocates a big block of memory (using ::operator new) in its constructor and uses it as a pool for memory allocations. The purpose is to speed up allocations for large numbers of small object.

My allocator at his bare level:

```
template<class _Ty>
struct bare_alloc {
    // Bare skeleton of my allocator

    bare_alloc(size_t _Amount) 
        : size_{ _Amount }, ptr_{ static_cast<_Ty*>(::operator new(sizeof(_Ty) * _Amount)) }
    { }
    bare_alloc(bare_alloc & ref)
        : bare_alloc{ ref.size_ }
    { }
    // Copy constructor used with rebind
    template<class _Oth>
    bare_alloc (const bare_alloc<_Oth> & ref) 
        : size_{ ref.size }, ptr_{ static_cast<_Oth*>(::operator new(sizeof(_Oth) * size_)) }
    { }
    ~bare_alloc() { /* Memory is automatically released */ }

    _Ty * allocate(size_t) { /* return a piece of the block
        and register that it has been claimed */ }
    void deallocate(_Ty*, size_t) { /* the piece claimed 
        may now be used again */ } 

    size_t size_;
    std::unique_ptr<_Ty> ptr_;
}
auto* ptr = myAlloc.allocate(10);
```

Anyway I've managed to track down the issue to these lines:

```
// Visual Studio, file 'list' line 678
void _Alloc_proxy()
    {   // construct proxy
    typename _Alty::template rebind<_Container_proxy>::other
        _Alproxy(_Getal()); 
    /* a call to the copy-constructor acquires resources (memory)*/
    _Myproxy() = _Alproxy.allocate(1);
    _Alproxy.construct(_Myproxy(), _Container_proxy());
    _Myproxy()->_Mycont = &_Get_data();
    } /* a call to _Alproxy's dctor releases resources */

// Complementary method to free the list's proxy
void _Free_proxy()
    {   // destroy proxy
    typename _Alty::template rebind<_Container_proxy>::other
        _Alproxy(_Getal());
    _Orphan_all();
    _Alproxy.destroy(_Myproxy());
    _Alproxy.deallocate(_Myproxy(), 1);
    _Myproxy() = 0;
    }
```

Clearly the `std::list` creates a temporary object of my allocator, allocates a block for its proxy, then the memory where it is situated is deallocated at the exit of the scope, causing, later on, the crash described above.

Therefore, my question is: **What's the best design *(i.e who should have the ownership of the allocated memory)* for my allocator, in accordance with the facts stated above** (for example, memory may outlive the allocator which allocated it)?

**EDIT:** Considering the lack of interest in that particular question i've decided to edit my question and explain my own solution to the problem:

Firstly the underlying memory is allocated at occurence using `::operator new[]` - i used `std::allocator::allocate()` for a while but it uses `::operator new` and gave me problem for allocations above 4096 bytes - and then I store the pointer in a `std::unique_ptr` which ensures the proper release. All those safe pointers are then stored in a `static std::vector`. Since it's static the memory is valid till the end of the program or manually deallocation. Later on i've built an allocator which manages that memory using information (size, last allocated chunk ...) stored in a `thread_local static std::vector< _BlockInfo<_Ty> >`. Since it's static (and thread-safe) the data remains valid no matter which particular instance works on it, thus this solves my problem.

***Any feedback or improvements are appreciated***

Comment: If the allocator is copied, wouldn't the copy have its own memory buffer? Does your allocator implement a copy constructor? Is the proxy really outliving the allocator that allocates it?

Comment: i'm pretty sure it is. from the debugger i see the proxy being allocated and constructed, then it follows a call to the allocator dctor. normally this isn't a problem since std::allocator doesn't own any resources since it's merely a wrapper. i could also be wrong, of course

Comment: also, each of the copy constructor allocates the memeory for its allocator

Comment: Allocators *must* be wrappers; their requirements preclude doing otherwise. Look at `std::polymorphic_allocator`'s design if you want inspiration.

Comment: thanks for pointing out the `polymorphic_allocator`, yet i'm not sure that its design really helps me

Comment: Would it work to use a `std::shared_ptr` instead and have the copy constructor do a shallow copy (i.e. what the default copy constructor would do anyway)?

Comment: I'm pretty sure i'm not leaking resources, infact the root of the problem is that memory is deallocated before the time has come ...

Comment: Anyway, using a `std::shared_ptr`, the problem would rise again because_Alproxy has a different type(_Container_proxy) then the one from which was copy constructed (_LinkNode<int, void*>), infact here it's used rebind. This also means that the allocators must points to different blocks of memory, one for each type, therefore in my program there would be one instance only of my allocator<_Container_proxy> and the memory would be released causing the crash after. Hope i have been somewhat clear. Added the copy ctr in case when rebind is called.

Comment: Note that the allocator written here is untested and simplified from the one i actually use, anyway it keeps traits that i think are necessary for the question

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking really. You wrote a non-compliant allocator that doesn't work and two comments above you acknowledge that it's hard to write one. Do you want an example of how to do it properly? It won't be short, and yes, allocators with different block sizes must be interchangeable for a given container, but containers tend to use them only with one block size - usually not the one related to T, but rebound to something else (T wrapped in a node, etc).